# Finding range of values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Is there a way in any of SQL formats, that allows to find a range of values in multiple columns.

Regular practice of a attaining solution I have is:

```
where 
      cost_price between my_budget_price and my_affordable_price
  or
      max_retail_price between my_budget_price and my_affordable_price

  or
      offer_price between my_budget_price and my_affordable_price
```

Here, the same `between ... values` clause is repeating on multiple columns.
I don't want to repeat it.

I am looking for something like this:

1. `where my_price in between ( cost_price, max_retail_price,
    offer_price )`
2. `where ( cost_price, max_retail_price, offer_price )

    between my_budget_price and my_affordable_price`

Comment: I don't think so. What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Nothing was wrong. I was just trying to stop repeating the comparison condition.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you could write a user defined function and perform any logic you wanted with the input parameters.

ie.

```
and 1 = my_udf(param1, param2, param3, param4)
```

then do whatever you want in the udf

```
 function my_udf(a varchar2, b varchar2, c varchar2, d varchar2) return number is
 begin
   if (any logic you want here) then
      return 1;
   else 
      return 2;
   end if;
 end;
```

Or more specifically:

```
select * 
  from some_table
 where 1 = my_udf(cost_price, max_retail_price, offer_price, 
                  my_budget_price, my_affordable_price)
```

and the function would go sometime like:

```
function my_udf(c number, r number, o number, l number, m number) return number is
begin
   if (c >= l and c <= m) or
      (r >= l and c <= m) or
      (o >= l and c <= m) then
      return 1;
   else
      return 2;
   end if; 
end;
```

This would do the same as:

```
select * 
  from some_table
 where (
        (cost_price       >= my_budget_price and cost_price       <= my_affordable_price)   
    or  (max_retail_price >= my_budget_price and max_retail_price <= my_affordable_price)
    or  (offer_price      >= my_budget_price and offer_price      <= my_affordable_price)
      )
```

Comment: Then, the function should be something like `fname( col_names_array[], least_boundary, max_bounday )`

Comment: Yeah.... I just updated the answer with a more specific example.  Hope this helps :)